# Reverse Function in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I Need Reverse Function in PHP for the Following JavaScript!

```
function jsrev(a) {
    return a.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, function(c) {
        return String.fromCharCode((c <= "Z" ? 90 : 122) >= (c = c.charCodeAt(0) + 13) ? c : c - 26)
    })
}
```

The above function convert string:-

`"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` to `"NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM"` in JavaScript

but i need function to reverse `2nd` string to `1st` in ***PHP***.

Comment: Have you tried some thing and faced any issues?

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse"? It would be a good idea to mention what your JS function does and what you want "reversed" in PHP. Additionally, you should be providing examples of your own code for solutions you've attempted so far. StackOverflow isn't a free coding service. You will receive help with figuring out where your code went wrong and what fixes you need to get things working, but you probably won't receive a solution to a problem you haven't proven that you've attempted to solve on your own.

Comment: The above function convert string "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" to "NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM" in Javascript but i need function to reverse 2nd string to 1st in PHP.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks proof that any effort was taken to solve problem yourself.

Comment: @BlackTiger  what is expected outcome you want in php?

Comment: I need a php function to convert string $jsrev "NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM" to "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" as i described in question!

eg:
function jsrev() {
    reverse $jsrev;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I voted down and flagged to close this question but.

Code you provided performs [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) operation. ROT13 is its own inverse, if you apply ROT13 twice you will get original string.

> ROT13( ROT13( x ) ) = x

There is built in function in PHP [str_rot13](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php), use it.

Comment: Works Perfect!
I Use echo str_rot13("NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM");
Thank-you so Much for Your Answer!